# how to change button value through user input

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

the scenario is like i have a  button when it appends onto the page it creates an object with some properties of that object and add that object in an array now the thing i want to do is having that button value and change it to what user want but at the same time it should update in array[object{button{value:''}}] . i tried but what it does is it over writes all button objects and i want every object to have its own value please help me thorugh this

```js
if (ui.draggable.data('type') == "button")
{ 
 document.getElementById('buttonDiv').style.display = "block";
 

 btn_id++;
    $( "<br><input type='submit' class='btn' id='btn-"+btn_id+"' value='buttonsss'>" ).text(ui.draggable.text()).appendTo( this ).click(function()
  {   
  
     var color= button['button'].color=$('#btn_color').val();
  var Bcolor= button['button'].Bcolor=$('#btn_bcolor').val();
  $(this).css('color',color);
  $(this).css('background',Bcolor);
  
  var value= $(this).val($('#btn_value').val());
     value= button['button'].value=$('#btn_value').val();
  
   $("#btn_remove").click(function(){
         $(this).remove();
   arr.splice(ui.draggable.data('type'),1);
   document.getElementById('buttonDiv').style.display = "none";
    });
  });
   
 var button = {
    button: {
  type: 'button',
        color: 'white',
        width: '15px',
  backgroundcolor:'white',
  value: ' My Button',
  id:'btn-"'+btn_id+'"',
  control:'button',
    name:'',
    label:'My Button',
    type:'',
  status:'',
  style:'',
   left:'',
    center:'',
     right:'',

    }
}
      var objectName = "button";
      arr.push(button);
```

```html
//for changing  button properties form
<div id="buttonDiv"  style="display:none;" class="answer_list" >  
color:<br>
<input id="btn_color" type="text" name="color">
<br>  
background-color:<br>     
<input id="btn_bcolor" type="text" name="Bcolor">
<br>
value:<br>     
<input id="btn_value" type="text" value="buttonname" placeholder="set your name">
<br>
Update component:<br>
<input id="update" type="button" value="update"/>
<br>
Remove component:<br>
<input id="btn_remove" type="button" value="remove"/>
</div>
```

kindly guide me through it would of great help thanks and i hope that everyone can get what iam trying to say.

Answer (score 0):

I was going to leave this as a comment but it became too big.

In your code you mix jQuery selectors with pure Javascript selectors, i.e. `document.getElementById('your-id')` can all be replaced by `$('#your-id')`. And then you can do `$('#buttonDiv').css('display', 'block')` instead.

The other thing is, when you use jQuery syntax `$('...')`, you are selecting something based on CSS (it expects CSS classes, ids and other related CSS identifiers, like HTML elements tags) therefore your `$( "<br><input type='submit' class='btn' id='btn-"+btn_id+"' value='buttonsss'>" ).text()` will not find a jQuery object where you can invoke the [`text` method](http://api.jquery.com/text/).

However, there is one exception: when you use immediately after the [`appendTo` method](http://api.jquery.com/appendto/) like this:

```
$( "<br><input type='submit' class='btn' id='btn-"+btn_id+"' value='buttonsss'>").appendTo("#buttonDiv")
```

Or, if you just want to move an existing object inside the `buttonDiv` then you can do:

```
$( "#btn_bcolor").appendTo($("#buttonDiv"));
```

After you do the desired corrections in your code and add the missing variables, people can help you better, and you can use jQuery inside the snippet in your question by selecting it in the dropdown menu of the snippet window at the top.

Comment: that is great thank you for pointing out these things as iam just a beginner this is of great help thank you let me fix everything you pointed out @armfoot